# Text file within the same directory as main Python file not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I have the next files inside a folder:
[image: Folder files]

When I execute `idsave.py` from within PyCharm or from the file location inside the command line it opens this file selection window when it's supposed to do it:
[image]

But if I run the desktop shortcut I made, it does not ask me to choose a file, when running `gtk-launch idsave.desktop` and click the button that triggers said window I get the next error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/username/Programacion/Python/idsave/idsave.py", line 39, in open_file
    dir_path = open('dir.txt', 'r')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'dir.txt'
```

Even though when checking if the file exists with `os.listdir()` it shows that the file in fact exists:

```
print(os.listdir(dir))
[file, file, file, 'dir.txt', 'idsave.py', file, file]
```

My `.desktop` shortcut looks like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=IdSave
GenericName=Idea Saver
Comment=Save Your Ideas
Exec=/home/username/Programacion/Python/idsave/idsave.py
Icon=/home/username/Programacion/Python/idsave/icon.jpg
Type=Application
Categories=Development;
```

The function that triggers that window is this:

```
def open_file():
  dir_path = open('dir.txt', 'r')
  root.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(
    initialdir=dir_path.readline(),
    filetypes=(("All Files", "*.*"))
  )
  dir_path.close()
```

I already tried with `'./dir.txt'` `'../dir.txt'` and the absolute path of the file, but the desktop entry still gives me the same error.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See  https://askubuntu.com/questions/262861/how-to-change-working-directory-when-open-a-file-with-double-clicking-on-ubuntu

Comment: Another simple way: give the full path to your file

Comment: Used path like this /home/username/Programacion/Python/idsave/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a desktop shortcut, you can create a bash script (.sh file) with the following code in a text editor and place it on your desktop. Name it `idsave.sh`.

```
cd "/home/username/Programacion/Python/idsave/"
python3 idsave.py
```

If on double-clicking the script doesn't run and opens your text editor instead, you can right click on `idsave.sh` and click on Properties. Then click on the Permissions tab and check `Allow executing file as program` (or something similar). Then click on `OK`.

Now you will be able to double click on `idsave.sh` and your Python program will launch as expected.

This will probably solve your problem.